# How to replace $(document).ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I got a problem and dont know how to fix it.
A have the following js script:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(1000).slideUp(1000, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }, 3000);
    $(document).on("click", "[data-hide]", function () {
        if (timer != null) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $(this).closest("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
        }
    });
});

<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@Model.AverageRaiting.ToString("# stars")</span>
    </h3>
    <span class="lead">@Model.Description</span>
    @Html.DialogFormLink("Update", Url.Action("UpdatePhoto", new {id = @Model.PhotoId}), "Update Photo", Url.Action("Photo"))
    @Html.Action("InitializeAlerts")//When this action is executing the document was already ready (by the first time when full page was loading), so I have no chanse to catch any .alerts in js alert file after updating this partial for another one.
</div>
```

Sometimes I have a situation when document is ready ealier than I have any `.alert` classes im my partial view. So, how to rewrite the function to execute it after my partial view is updated with valid `.alert`?

Comment: Have you tried `$(window).load()`?

Comment: Try $.on for binding fadeTo event with `.alert` class

Comment: @MokshShah could you write the full example how to bind? That is probably I need.

Comment: What about having your partial view have an "is ready" flag / class that you wait for / check with a timeout/promise

Comment: You either need to wait around for `$(".alert")` to exist first, or you need to add your code inside the loading processing. Please show all related code (as per your previous similar question) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie the code and problem are same:) I need to execute the function with `$(",alert")` class after my another js file finished updating partial view.

Comment: Added an alternative below using a custom triggered message to let other files know "a panel was loaded".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to wait around for `$(",alert")` to exist first, or you need to add your code inside the loading processing.

If you do not wish to couple your JS files tightly, you can broadcast a "panel loaded" event from the other script, which you catch at the document level.

e.g.

```
$.ajax({...}).done(function(loadedhtml){
    $somepanel.html(loadedhtml);
    $(document).trigger("panelloaded", $somepanel);
});
```

and listen for the generic "panel loaded" event in your main:

e.g.

```
$(document).on('panelloaded', function(panel){
    // Do stuff here to the newly loaded panel
});
```

Comment: Thanks for so fast helping. Although I have my doubts about this decision by the global triggers. Is it not very bad solution?

Comment: @user3818229: Why on Earth would you consider "global triggers" a bad thing? It depends on how you use (or misuse) them, but they are a very useful way of notifying unrelated elements of events occurring. That is specifically what they are for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you reload your Partial View i suppose the best thing is to place your code in [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) function.

It will be ready rigth after your ajax request done.

Comment: The reason I don't do that because my partial updating from another js file and after I want to reload my timer function.

Comment: @user3818229 don't you want to give your function name. and call it in 2 places?

Comment: Not really. Because the second script is the template for all dialog forms so I don't wan to make hard code in it.